# How to write update set in zend db?

Tags: php, mysql

Please Suggest me how to write this using zend db

```
$userId = $_GET ['user_id'];
$statsFalg = $_GET['stats_flag'];
$query = UPDATE users SET stats_flag='".$statsFlag."' WHERE user_id='".$userId."';
```

Actually I'm sending an request through Ajax when the user checked box or unchecked a box

Comment: for the good of humanity, I sincerely hope that the `$userId` variable is properly sanitized

Comment: You mean properly `escaped` unlike what the XKCD comic says, input into the DB is escaped, output is sanitized :-).

Comment: If using Zend_Db properly, no escaping or sanitization is necessary. Zend_Db handles it for you, as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this in the update function of your model:

```
$data = array(
    'stats_flag' => 0,
);
$this->getDbTable()->update($data, array('user_id = ?' => $userId));
```

Where `getDbTable()` returns an instance of `Zend_Db_Table_Abstract`:

```
class Application_Model_DbTable_User extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
{
    protected $_schema = 'test';
    protected $_name = 'user';  
}
```